# Matlab, how to apply medfilt2 function on specific pixel locations

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is there a way if I want to apply medfilt2 function to the specific pixel locations rather than the whole image? The pixel locations can be represented using a binary image called IMask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lazy method is to just apply `medfilt2` on the whole image and then copy the specific locations. E.g.

```
A = magic(10); % sample matrix
IMask = logical(randi([0 1],10)); % sample locations

B = medfilt2(A);
A(IMask) = B(IMask);
```

Not very elegant, but will do the job unless your matrix is gigantic and `IMask` is mostly false.

Comment: This is the fastest way unfortunately.  `medfilt2` is accelerated by Intel IPP and optionally CUDA if you have the Parallel Computing Toolbox, and so branching and finding exceptions for pixels not to be filtered would break the flow.  This is quite common in CUDA and OpenCL for example.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the point but if you define the matrix you are passing to `medfilt2` is a subset of your image that you want being processed **but you have to take care of the padding** (zeros/symmetric/etc values at the boundaries).

Afterwards, you just have to replace the processed matrix within the image at the right position.